# Expression for telling someone to stop being deluded/lying to themselves?

Tags: phrase-requests

When someone is self-deluded and you would like to use an expression to tell them to basically look in the mirror and see the truth, what would this expression be?

This person is the type to be extremely narrow minded and only see things their way, even when this is not correct or realistic. This person therefore lies to themselves and lives in a deluded sense. Always thinking that they are right and others are wrong, never wanting to see things for what they are because they don't want to have to admit that they're wrong.

Comment: It's called "beating your head against a brick wall".  You can't convince such a person that they're wrong -- they have to undergo some sort of self-revelation.

Answer (score 6):

**Wake up and smell the coffee.**

> something that you say in order to tell someone that they should try
>   to understand the true facts of a situation or that they should give
>   more attention to what is happening around them
>
> *It's time you woke up and smelled the coffee, Don. We're just not getting enough business any more.*

[Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Wake+up+and+smell+the+coffee!
)

Comment: Also, just "[wake up](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/wake_up)".

Answer (score 4):

TFD(idioms):

> **[get real](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+real)**
>
> to accept the truth and not deceive yourself 
>   Voters want Congress to
>   **get real** and pass a bill to revive the economy.
>
> Usage notes: also used as an order:   You expect me to ignore data
>   like that? **Get real!**
>
> Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge
>   University Press 2003. Reproduced with permission.

Answer (score 1):

**Stop living in fantasy land.**

There are a number of variations ("fantasy land" as one word or two, with or without an article, "world" instead of "land").

Various similar definitions: "fantasy land" is [an imagined, idealized place.  (Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fantasyland)  To live in a fantasy land is [to have ideas or plans that are not realistic. (M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live%20in%20a%20fantasy%20world)

Another variation on fantasy land is "la-la land" (variations in capitalization and hyphenation).  These expressions are interchangeable, but a definition for living in la-la land is [to think that things that are completely impossible might happen, rather than understanding how things really are. (Cambridge)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/la-la-land)

Answer (score 1):

***Stop hiding/putting/sticking your head in the sand!***

[****hide/stick/put/bury (one's) head in the sand****](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hide+(one%27s)+head+in+the+sand)

: to refuse to deal with unpleasant realities, possible dangers, etc. by pretending they do not exist.

The term comes from the practice of ostriches, who spend a good deal of time burrowing headfirst in the sand. Most of the time they are eating, for these large, flightless birds consume sand and gravel, which are used in their gizzards to help digest food. However, it was long thought that they put their heads down in the mistaken belief that they then cannot be seen, and from the early seventeenth century on this mythical self-delusion was transferred to human beings who are avoiding unpleasantness.

"Stop sticking your head in the sand, Tim. Don’t pretend that everything’s all right."

"Lou, you can't hide your head in the sand about your health—please, make an appointment with your doctor and get that rash checked out!"

A: "How has Peter been handling the breakup?" B: "Oh, just putting his head in the sand and ignoring his feelings."

"Stop burying your head in the sand. Look at the statistics on smoking and cancer."

[idioms.thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bury%2fhide+one%27s+head+in+the+sand%2c+to)